# How to plot white points with black outline in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to create a scatterplot using ggplot2 in R where the points are white with black outlines. Consider the following data:

```
d <- data.frame(x = 1:5,
                y = sample(1:5))

  x y
1 1 2
2 2 4
3 3 3
4 4 5
5 5 1
```

```
ggplot(data = d,
       mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Try `geom_point(shape = 21, fill = "white", color = "black")`

Answer (score 0):

To do this, create two `geom_point` layers with one smaller white point on top of a larger black point:

```
ggplot(data = d,
       mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size = 3, color = "black") +
  geom_point(size = 2, color = "white")
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but can be a pain to modify due to duplication. Using `geom_point(shape = 21, fill = "white", color = "black")` would be better.